# Paypal php script won't work

Tags: php, paypal

When I try this script is that the payment is successful but when I'm redirected it says that it has failed! What do I do here!

index.php file

```
    <?php
$paypal_url='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; // Test Paypal API URL
$paypal_id='CENSORING MY PAYPAL EMAIL'; // Business email ID
?>
    <div class="btn">
    <form action="<?php echo $paypal_url ?>" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="PHPGang Payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="credits" value="510">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://23.95.189.209/coen/test/cancel.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://23.95.189.209/coen/test/success.php">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form> 
    </div>
</div>

<?php
$title = "PayPal Payment in PHP";
$heading = "Welcome to PayPal Payment PHP example.";
?>
```

success.php file

```
    <?php
$item_no            = $_REQUEST['item_number'];
$item_transaction   = $_REQUEST['tx']; // Paypal transaction ID
$item_price         = $_REQUEST['amt']; // Paypal received amount
$item_currency      = $_REQUEST['cc']; // Paypal received currency type

$price = '10.00';
$currency='USD';

//Rechecking the product price and currency details
if($item_price==$price && $item_currency==$currency)
{
    echo "Successful Payment";
}
else
{
    echo "Failed Payment";
}

?>
```

Im not sure why this won't work!
The business email ID is my own but I have taken it out here though.

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, see what's actually coming into the success script, instead of just assuming those values will always be there.

Comment: `array(0) { }` that is whats there. So nothings being sent, how do I get things to send?

Comment: array(0){} after payment in paypal?

Comment: Do you see any error in paypal?

Comment: Nope says payment successful

Comment: array(0) { } on the success page after the payment